# Spring DriverManagerDataSource- stack overflow during driver loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datasource, spring-bean

I defined a data source as the following :

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource();
}
```

During spring's bootstrapping, console is throwing a massive:

```
Dez 07, 2016 5:00:53 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
```

and after a while I'm getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class sample.config.AppConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource sample.config.AppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

All the sample I've copied from some book, what can be wrong here?

Could the problem be, that I've put it into web application config class?

Comment: Do you have h2 driver jar file in your libs folder??

Comment: Yes, I have added a h2 maven dependency and Driver is in libs.

Comment: Please edit dataSource() to dataSource.

Comment: Of course! What a stupid mistake! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Please close or delete a question- I can not make it (because there is already an answer). There was a basic programming mistake in code and it has nothing to add in a topic of initializing in Spring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `dataSource()` bean creation method change the return statement to:

```
return dataSource;
```

You are calling the method again, this is creating the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you are recursively calling your own method and at the end it will through the stackoverflowerror.